# Client - Server Web application

Tags: javascript, c++, browser, web

I am totally new to web development and I am trying to create a network game.I already implemented most of the game logics in C++ and I wanted to utilize this. It includes most of the logic but does not have graphic features. I believe that client would handle this.

Suppose I am running a game logic on `127.0.0.1:8000`(with C++ language). 
Then how could I display graphic features such as sprite using a browser? Is it possible to execute client code when you access using browser?

This is my plan:

Client Side:Representing graphical feature(Gui...) from the information that is sent from the server.

Server side: Handle all game logic

Please correct me if it does not make sense at all.

Comment: What kind of game mechanic is it? Realtime, or user event driven?

Comment: It is a 2-player tetris.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure if it is realtime or user event driven. Each player send key strokes to the server, server applies the keystrokes to the logic, and send back the updated game state. Two players need to be synchronized but I haven't implemented that far.

Comment: The reason I ask is that if it's user event driven (not the best term), you could make the program like you would a typical website - with state changing on each request, and AJAX to prevent full page reloads. This won't be a suitable approach for you though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Are you saying that I just need to develop a HTML page which communicates to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using [HTML canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/) alongside [WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

It's worth noting that these are relatively new features and so aren't compatible with older browsers.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I definitely need to use socket.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a TCP socket from a client-side web application?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think you are limited to WebSockets client-side